# How do I know which macros are built-in / predefined in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor

I am working with the Clang preprocessor and I would to know which macros are built-in or predefined. For example, this is predefined:

```
#define __clang__ 1
```

I can get the list as a big string using `getPredefines()`, however I would prefer to not have to parse it myself.

Is there a flag on the preprocessor objects that will let me know which macros are predefined?

I have tried things like `getBuiltinID`, but not had any luck.